# how to handle multiple UISlider value in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, uislider

I have three `UISlider` namely `slider 1`: to scale, `slider 2`: to adjust left/right and `slider 3`: to adjust top/bottom position.

When `slider 1` (scale) is adjusted, when adjusting `slider 2`(left/right) `scnnode` is not adjusted same scale value, it reduces to original scale value.

here is my code of three slider value:

```
 @IBAction func didChangedSlider(_ sender: Any) {

    switch slider.value {

    case 0 ... 25 :
        earsNode1.scale    = SCNVector3(0.0011, 0.0011, 0.0011)
        earsNode.scale     = SCNVector3(0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010)

        earsNode.position  = SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.035, -0.12)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.077, -0.035, -0.12)

        isSizeIncreased = false

    case 25 ... 50 :
        earsNode1.scale    = SCNVector3(0.0014, 0.0014, 0.0014)
        earsNode.scale     = SCNVector3(0.0014, 0.0014, 0.0014)

        earsNode.position  = SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.040, -0.12)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.077, -0.040, -0.12)

        isSizeIncreased = true

    case 50 ... 75 :

        earsNode1.scale    = SCNVector3(0.002, 0.002, 0.002)
        earsNode.scale     = SCNVector3(0.002, 0.002, 0.002)

        earsNode.position  = SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.050, -0.12)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.077, -0.050, -0.12)

        isSizeIncreased = true

    case 75 ... 100 :
        earsNode1.scale    = SCNVector3(0.003, 0.003, 0.003)
        earsNode.scale     = SCNVector3(0.003, 0.003, 0.003)

        earsNode.position  = SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.064, -0.12)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.077, -0.064, -0.12)

        isSizeIncreased = true

    default:
        print("slider value \(slider.value)")
    }
}

// slider2 - left/right

@IBAction func didChangedSliderLeftOrRight(_ sender: Any) {

    switch slider2.value {
    case 0 ... 25:

        earsNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.083, -0.035, -0.099)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.083, -0.035, -0.099)

    case 25 ... 50:

        earsNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.081, -0.035, -0.099)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.081, -0.035, -0.099)

    case 50 ... 75:

        earsNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.077, -0.035, -0.099)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.077, -0.035, -0.099)

    case 75 ... 100:

        earsNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.073, -0.035, -0.099)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.073, -0.035, -0.099)

    default:
        print("slider2 value \(slider2.value)")

    }
}

// slider3 - top/bottom

@IBAction func didChangedSliderTopOrBottom(_ sender: Any) {

    switch slider3.value {
    case 0 ... 25:


        earsNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.079, -0.027, -0.099)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.079, -0.027, -0.099)

    case 25 ... 50:


        earsNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.079, -0.031, -0.099)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.079, -0.031, -0.099)

        if isSizeIncreased {

            earsNode.position  = SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.040, -0.12)
            earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.077, -0.040, -0.12)
        }

    case 50 ... 75:


        earsNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.079, -0.035, -0.099)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.079, -0.035, -0.099)

        if isSizeIncreased {

            earsNode.position  = SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.054, -0.12)
            earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.077, -0.054, -0.12)
        }

    case 75 ... 100:


        earsNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.079, -0.039, -0.099)
        earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.079, -0.039, -0.099)

        if isSizeIncreased {

            earsNode.position  = SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.060, -0.12)
            earsNode1.position = SCNVector3(0.077, -0.060, -0.12)
        }

    default:
        print("slider3 value \(slider3.value)")

    }
  }
}
```

here is my screenshot

[image]

My issue is when user change any slider value, its not changing from last position of slider adjusted.
Slider value should be adjusted from already adjusted position.

Answer (score 1):

Copy/Paste and Save in Xcode this file https://gist.github.com/jeremyconkin/a3909b2d3276d1b6fbff02cefecd561a

When use Vector Math in your sliders (I rewrite only 1st):

```
@IBAction func didChangedSlider(_ sender: Any) {

switch slider.value {

case 0 ... 25 :
    earsNode1.scale    += SCNVector3(0.0011, 0.0011, 0.0011)
    earsNode.scale     += SCNVector3(0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010)

    earsNode.position  += SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.035, -0.12)
    earsNode1.position += SCNVector3(0.077, -0.035, -0.12)

    isSizeIncreased = false

case 25 ... 50 :
    earsNode1.scale    += SCNVector3(0.0014, 0.0014, 0.0014)
    earsNode.scale     += SCNVector3(0.0014, 0.0014, 0.0014)

    earsNode.position  += SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.040, -0.12)
    earsNode1.position += SCNVector3(0.077, -0.040, -0.12)

    isSizeIncreased = true

case 50 ... 75 :

    earsNode1.scale    += SCNVector3(0.002, 0.002, 0.002)
    earsNode.scale     += SCNVector3(0.002, 0.002, 0.002)

    earsNode.position  += SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.050, -0.12)
    earsNode1.position += SCNVector3(0.077, -0.050, -0.12)

    isSizeIncreased = true

case 75 ... 100 :
    earsNode1.scale    += SCNVector3(0.003, 0.003, 0.003)
    earsNode.scale     += SCNVector3(0.003, 0.003, 0.003)

    earsNode.position  += SCNVector3(-0.08, -0.064, -0.12)
    earsNode1.position += SCNVector3(0.077, -0.064, -0.12)

    isSizeIncreased = true

default:
    print("slider value \(slider.value)")
}
```

}

Comment: for an example if slider 1 is to move the node from left to right and slider 2 is to move from top to bottom. if slider 1 is moved to right side and when adjusting slider 3 it should move up/down from right side not from the origin.

Comment: could you help out of this?

Comment: Now I understand you! The issue is not in Sliders at all.
It's on the 3d math!

Comment: You should use SCNVector3 Math here.
Example:
https://gist.github.com/jeremyconkin/a3909b2d3276d1b6fbff02cefecd561a


     earsNode.position += SCNVector3(-0.079, -0.035, -0.099)

Comment: Check my answer above.

Comment: thanks!! let check me and back to you..if doubt on this can i ping u?